# MVC: Is it a "good practice" to pass a model from a ViewController to another?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

In my app, in which I'm adopting the **MVC** architecture, I have two different Controllers which use basically the same model class.

Since this model class on `init` unarchives an entire object graph using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` initializing a new instance of the class when passing to the new controller may get kinda expensive in terms of resources.

So I was wondering if it would be "good practice" to pass a pointer to the already initialized model class of the first controller to the second controller instead of creating a new instance from scratch.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Pretty sure one of the core concepts of MVVC is that each view has exactly one model...

Comment: Uhm maybe I wan't clear or maybe I didn't get your point, if so I'm sorry but I'm no native english speaker and, most importantly I'm new to MVC. Anyways I'm not talking about having two models in a single controller, I'm talking about two controllers sharing the same model.

Comment: OK, I recommend changing your title... a ViewController is MVVC, a derivative of MVC.  Generally speaking, you want a model class per view (which is, by default, per controller).  This allows you to place controller-specific business validation logic into the model.  If you are using the same model for more than one controller, your controllers are probably being redundant.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs In the context of iOS development, controllers are (usually) known as view controllers but the paradigm is still commonly known as [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). Also, there's no need to tie model classes to views -- the whole point is to decouple the way data is stored and operated on from the way it's displayed and entered. There's no need to change the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I was wondering if it would be "good practice" to pass a pointer to
>   the already initialized model class of the first controller to the
>   second controller instead of creating a new instance from scratch.

Sure, that's fine if the two controllers are supposed to operate on the same data. The view controller really shouldn't depend on where the model comes from -- it should just use the one that you give it. That keeps your view controller flexible -- it means that you can always use the same controller with a different instance of the model.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason for separation of Model, View and Controller so you can mix and match like this with ease, without worrying about crazy refactoring.  So yes, you can and it is encouraged.  How else would controllers share data, especially when you're using the drill-down navigation UI on the iPhone, for example.